# Не реагирует на callback кнопки aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, callback

Не реагирует на Callback кнопку verifyButton

```
import asyncio
import logging
import time
botnick='#У меня тут ник бота'

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram import executor
from aiogram.types import ContentType, Message
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.types.chat_permissions import ChatPermissions
from config_reader import config
from text import *
from login import *
from design import *
chat_id1=0
token=config.bot_token.get_secret_value()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
urlkb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
urlButton = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пройти верификацию', url=f'https://t.me/{botnick}?start=verify')
urlkb.add(urlButton)
urkkb2 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
urlkb2 = InlineKeyboardButton('Я прочитал❗', callback_data='verifyButton')
urkkb2.insert(urlkb2)
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS])
async def new_members_handler(message: Message):
    global chat_id1;
    new_member = message.new_chat_members[0]
    await message.bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, new_member.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False))
    chat_id1=message.chat.id
    msg_welcome=await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, welcome, reply_markup=urlkb)
@dp.message_handler(regexp='/start')
async def verify(message: types.Message):
    if '/start verify'==message.text:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, welcome2, reply_markup=urkkb2)
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="verifyButton")
async def verify2(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global chat_id1;
    await call.message.delete()
    await call.answer(text="Вы успешно прошли верификацию!", show_alert=True)
    await bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id1, call.message.chat.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=True))
    try:
        await msg_welcome.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ошибка")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Бот работает, но при нажатии на кнопку с функцией verifyButton нет никакой реакции

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(Text(startwith="verifyButton"))
async def verify2(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global chat_id1;
    await call.message.delete()
    await call.answer(text="Вы успешно прошли верификацию!", show_alert=True)
    await bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id1, call.message.chat.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=True))
    try:
        await msg_welcome.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ошибка")
```

Comment: @dp.callback_query_handler(Text(startwith="verifyButton"))
NameError: name 'Text' is not defined. Did you mean: 'next'?

Comment: from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text

Comment: @КлараНуриева from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text

Comment: TypeError: Text.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'startwith'

Comment: с ошибкой разобрались, но все равно, нет никакой реакции бота